# Bootstrap theme overrides "theme_list_item" function and removes div's "item-list" class

Tags: theming

How can I stop Bootstrap theme from overriding the them_item_list and replacing the div's class from item-list to panel-body?

I have the following form and it does not render the items

```
$stages = array(
1 => array('data' => '1. Step 1'),
2 => array('data' => '2. Step 2'),
3 => array('data' => '3. Step 3'),
);

$stages[$current_step]['class'] = array('active');

$stages_list = theme('item_list', array('items' => $stages));

$form['header'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => '',
    '#value' => $stages_list,
);
```

the Above renders a navigation steps menu just fine with Bartik and other themes however, when it comes to Bootstrap it  is empty rather having list of items.

I did some googling and found out [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2388415) issue that might be somewhat relevant but, the solution does not seem to work for me. I tried to override the mytheme_item_list($variables) in template.php with following but, still no sign of the naviagtion.

```
function bootstrap_subtheme_item_list($variables) {
   $items = $variables['items'];
   $title = $variables['title'];
   $type = $variables['type'];
   $attributes = $variables['attributes'];

   $output = '<div class="item-list">';
   $output .= "<$type" . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>';


   $count = 1;
   $num_items = count($items);

   foreach ($items as $item) {
      $attributes = array();
      $children = array();
      $data = '';
      $count++;

      if (is_array($item)) {
        foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
          if ($key == 'data') {
            $data = $value;
          }
          elseif ($key == 'children') {
            $children = $value;
          }
          else {
            $attributes[$key] = $value;
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        $data = $item;
      }

      if (count($children) > 0) {
        // Render nested list.
        $data .= theme_item_list(array('items' => $children, 'title' => NULL, 'type' => $type, 'attributes' => $attributes));
      }

      if ($count == 1) {
        $attributes['class'][] = 'first';
      }
      if ($count == $num_items) {
        $attributes['class'][] = 'last';
      }
      $output .= '<li' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>' . $data . "</li>\n";
   }
   $output .= "</$type></div>";


   dpm($output);

   return $output;
 }
```

The dpm above prints the exact thing piece of html that I want, the following but, the same is not rendered in the page.

```
<div class="item-list"><ul><li class="active">1. Step 1</li>
<li class="last">2. Step 2</li>
<li>3. Step 3</li>
</ul></div>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any solution that do not break other theme's would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**1) Default markup.** To return default item list markup just do this:

```
function bootstrap_subtheme_item_list($variables) {
  return theme_item_list($variables);
}
```

**2) But.** Your issue is not caused by Bootstrap markup. Try this:

```
$form['header'] = array(
  '#markup' => $stages_list,
);
```

You are using `fieldset` incorrectly, learn [Form API Reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html).